# What account do I use to remote desktop into VM on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Office 365 account where I am admin. I used that same account to create an Azure space or account, where I "believe" or "should" be admin as well. In both cases, I am the only user. Both work fine and I can log into both with same user name and password. I created an RDP connection to a VM that I create in Azure. The only user name and password that I would know of to use is the same one that I log into Azure with, but it never works. Seems to be connecting but just rejecting credentials. What username should I use? I can't use one that I create on the VM because I can't get on there yet.

Answer (score 4):

When you create a VM you need to give it admin username and password. And you would use those to login, so check what you did input and use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the existing user password or create the new user/password from the 'Reset Password' option from the Azure Portal as well.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use the name of the domain of the VM in front of my username to get in.